# ComboBox searching in string, not just the first letter

Tags: c#, string, search, combobox

I have problem making my combobox searching inside the strings in the items.
I want to narrow down a list of members. They are formatted in this way (unique member id) - First name - last name.

When i leave all the settings "as is", then it will only "allow" me to search at the first char in the string.

The DataSource is set from a  list, what are made from looping through all the files in a folder.   ​

The code i have been using is as follows(partial code)

```
    private void searchForShooterComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //if(e => KeyCode == Keys::Down || e => KeyCode == Keys::Down)
        //string comboBoxValue = searchForShooterComboBox.Text;
        //searchForShooterComboBox.DataSource = null;
        //searchForShooterComboBox.DataSource = fliterComboBox(searchForShooterComboBox, memberFileNames);
        //searchForShooterComboBox.Text = comboBoxValue;
    }

    private void searchForShooterComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchForShooterComboBox.DataSource = null;
        searchForShooterComboBox.DataSource = fliterComboBox(searchForShooterComboBox, memberFileNames);
    }
private List<string> fliterComboBox(ComboBox cobx, List<string> stringList)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        if (cobx.Text != ""){
            try
            {
                foreach (string s in stringList)
                {
                    if (s.Contains(cobx.Text))
                    {
                        returnList.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }catch{
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

some of the code i tried seemed to filter the list OK, but after the methods ran it fills what seems to be the first item in the new list into the "text field", so the user wont be able to continue typing a name ex.

Will it make any difference using `ComboBox.Items.Add()` and `ComboBox.Items.Remove()` instead of using `DataSource`?

edit: the comboBox DataSource is initially set in the form_load event handler. Where the following code regarding the combobox is:

```
searchForShooterComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
searchForShooterComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
searchForShooterComboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
```

Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: This "filling the first item into the text field", I would say it's a default behaviour. It happens for me as well, whenever I first add something into a combobox, no matter if it's one or more. It happens by default when you first add something dynamically to the combobox, either by datasource or by just normal comboBox.Items.Add(stringhere) to it.

Comment: okay, i was wondering if it would be better to sort the strings using the ComboBox.Items.RemoveAt (know that cant be done when the datasource is set) instead, but thought i would be easier to "reset" the list using the datasource. I looked for a property to remove the initial "fill" but couldn't seem to find any. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: I would recommend you update your question with what you asked in your comment accordingly, so others can answer that directly :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay seems i figured something out myself,don't know if its the best way, but seems to get the job done :)

firstly i added the string's into both the `ComboBox.items` and into a `list<string>`. The reason for adding them both ways is for the user to see all available options on load.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < membersFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            searchForShooterComboBox.Items.Add(membersFiles[i].Replace(".txt", "").Replace(@"C:\Users\Nicolai\Desktop\skytter\", "").Replace("-", " "));
            memberFileNames.Add(membersFiles[i].Replace(".txt", "").Replace(@"C:\Users\Nicolai\Desktop\skytter\", "").Replace("-", " "));
        }
```

After that i added a combobox_keydown event from the property window.

```
private void searchForShooterComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //checking if the key pressed is RETURN, in that case try to fill the combobox with the selected item,
            //and continuing with other method
            if (e.KeyValue == 13)
            {
                searchForShooterComboBox.Text = (string)searchForShooterComboBox.SelectedItem;
                fillInfoInForm();
            }
            //making sure the key pressed IS NOT DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT arrow key.
            else if (e.KeyValue > 40 || e.KeyValue < 37)
            {
                filterComboBox(searchForShooterComboBox, searchForShooterComboBox.Text);
                searchForShooterComboBox.Select(searchForShooterComboBox.Text.Length, 0);
                searchForShooterComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Der blev ikke fundet nogen fil med flg. sti " + ex.FileName + "\nHusk at vælge hele navnet i listen, eller skriv det nøjagtigt som det står!");
        }
    }
```

made this method to search through the list items, clear the items in the combobox, and add the ones that match.

```
    private void filterComboBox(ComboBox cobx, string enteredSearch)
    {
        //clearing ComboBox items before adding the items from the LIST that meets the search
        cobx.Items.Clear();

        //looping over the items from the list, comparing them to the search from the combobox text field.
        //if the item in the list does not contain the string searched it will return an index of -1.
        for (int i = memberFileNames.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (memberFileNames[i].IndexOf(enteredSearch, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                cobx.Items.Add(memberFileNames[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

if you are having trouble finding the right KeyValues, try looking at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keyvalue(v=vs.110).aspx
and copy paste the code from there, and add it to you key_down event handler, and it will show most info(if not all) in a message box.

That was my workaround, if you have a better way of doing it, i am all ears :)